# How to save file location in a text box from dialog browser

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have the following code that I have written to try to open the file browser, and then save the file location into a text box. So far I can open the file browser but cant get it to save the path into my text box

```
Private Sub txtImageName_Click()
  Dim f As Object
  Dim strFile As String
  Dim strFolder As String
  Dim varItem As Variant

  Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)
  f.AllowMultiSelect = True
  If f.Show Then
    For Each varItem In f.SelectedItems
        strFile = Dir(varItem)
        strFolder = Left(varItem, Len(varItem) - Len(strFile))
        MsgBox "Folder: " & strFolder & vbCrLf & _
            "File: " & strFile
    Next
  End If
  Set f = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To save the Folder and File to a textbox:

```
Private Sub txtImageName_Click()
  Dim f As Object
  Dim strFile As String
  Dim strFolder As String
  Dim varItem As Variant

  Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)
  f.AllowMultiSelect = True
  If f.Show Then
    For Each varItem In f.SelectedItems
        strFile = Dir(varItem)
        strFolder = Left(varItem, Len(varItem) - Len(strFile))
        MsgBox "Folder: " & strFolder & vbCrLf & _
            "File: " & strFile
        Me.YourTextbox = strFolder & "\" & strFile <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< ADD THIS LINE
    Next
  End If
  Set f = Nothing
End Sub
```